# How to get a reference to a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, namespaces

i'm studying by the book C++ the programming languague, in the page 30 chapter 2, bjarne make something like :

```
namespace Stack
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 200;
    struct Rep;
    typedef Rep& stack;

    stack create();
    void destroy(stack s);

    void push(stack s, int i);
    int pop(stack s);
}
```

the struct :

```
struct Stack::Rep
{
    int ar[200];
    int top;
};
```

i'm trying return the reference in the function `Stack::create()` , but i cant do it, a try a lot of methods, but i ever get some error.

```
"initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue" : 

Stack::stack Stack::create()
{
   Stack::stack s = new Rep();
}

"reference variable "s" requires an initializer"

Stack::stack Stack::create()
{
   Stack::stack s;
}
```

i dont know where i'm wrong, could someone help me and explain if possible.

Comment: All errors are reasonable. In first `create` you try to assign a pointer to a reference. In second, you try to create empty reference. This is not possible, a reference must be connected with something.

Comment: You might want to continue reading on page 31. :-)  There Bjarne shows how he implements this *without* using `new`, but instead preallocates space and returns a reference to that. (And anyway, you should consider getter a later edition of the book so you don't learn C++98).

Comment: @BoPersson, i saw this, but i really wanna to learn how to do this dynamically. thank you anywhere, could you recommend another book instead the c++ programming language, i could use the both.

Comment: @BadLuiz - You will learn a lot more later in the book, this is just an introduction. The page number tells us that you are using the 3rd edition of the book, which covers C++98. The 4th edition, covering C++11, contains an additional 400 pages so is quite different. The language itself *also* changed quite a bit in those years.

Comment: I will get this version of book, and thank you @BoPersson.

Comment: Please don't hide a reference (or pointer) behind a typedef. i.e. don't do `typedef SomeType& SomeName;` or `typedef SomeType* SomeName;`. It only leads to confusion when you use it.

Answer (score 1):

`stack` is a typedef: `typedef Rep& stack;`. Think of your functions if you replace this `typedef`:

```
Stack::stack s = new Rep();
=
Rep& s = new Rep(); // Can't work, `new` returns a pointer (not a reference)
                    // which you assign to a reference!

Stack::stack s;
=
Rep& s; // A reference cannot exist without being assigned!
```

Since you are returning a reference, the structure must exist somewhere accessible to the caller. Something akin to:

```
namespace Stack
{
...
Rep myGlobalStack;

stack create() {
    return myGlobalStack;
}
```

*I am not suggesting you do it this way. Just pointing out where you are going wrong.*

Comment: Fantastic Mr Fox, thank you by the suggestion, i thought do it, but now is a question of "challenge" do it like the book recommend, do you know how could i initialize this struct ? i create a constructor in the Struct Rep and call in the function create, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write create() function in this way:

```
Stack::stack Stack::create()
{
      Stack::Rep *r = new Rep();
      return *r ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you by the suggestion.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. If you do this, the user will have to do this if they want to free the memory correctly: `Stack::stack ref = Stack::create(); delete &ref` (which is gross). And if they do this, it will immediately leak memory: `Stack::Rep rep = Stack::create()`.